# GDAL_Merge not included in OSGEO4W window

Tags: qgis, gdal, osgeo4w, gdal-merge

I download QGIS Desktop 3.18.3 which came with OSGEO4W

I ran `o-help` on the OSGEO4W window and noticed gdal_merge etc werent included as available commands. Yet if I go to `apps/python37/scripts` folder of QGIS gdal_merge etc is installed there.

How can I get all the gdal commands to be available in the OSGEO4W window?

Comment: Never mind, I have found the answer in this thread!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633487/gdal-merge-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-in-osgeo4w

Comment: Guest please add the substance of that answer below, and accept it (run `py3_env` first. ) It's okay to answer your own questions on Stack Exchange!. There's a good chance somone else will have the same problem.